# 仮想マシンでのファイルダウンロードが正しく行われません。

Tags: centos, vagrant, virtualbox

#### 困っていること

利用している仮想化OS(CentOS 8)でファイルのダウンロードが正しく行われない。
(実行環境については、下部**発生環境**をご参照ください)

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.2/Python-3.9.2.tgz
md5sum Python-3.9.2.tgz
```

上記コマンドの実行結果が毎回異なってしまいます。ホストOS（Windows）のターミナルで実施した場合は毎回同じ値になり、ホストOS上WSLのUbuntuで実行した際の値とまったく同じ。ゲストOSで実行した場合に限り異なる。
この現象は`vagrant destroy ⇒　vagrant up`しても変わることはなしでした。

この事象の原因などご存じの方がいればご教示お願いします。

#### 直接の発生現象

`pip3 install numpy`した場合にファイルのchecksum値が異なることに起因してエラーとなる事象からスタートして
上記のようにこの環境でwgetなりしたファイルすべてが毎回異なるmd5sum値を持つことに気が付きました。

#### ほかに試したこと

Windows 10 home(詳細は下記お試し環境を参照ください。)のインストールされている環境では期待通りファイルはダウンロードされ `pip install numpy` も動作しました。
環境をそろえて試してみたいのですが、現状動作している環境は温存し、作業を推進していきたいので、おいそれと手を出すことができず。当面の作業完了まで手が出せません。すいません。

**発生環境**

- Processor: AMD Ryzen 3600x
- メモリ： 32GB
- 仮想化ソフト：Oracle VirtualBox 6.1
- 仮想化運用：Vagrant 2.2.14
- ホストOS: Windows 10 Pro 20H2
- ゲストOS: CentOS 8 (Vagrantのcentos/8=公式BOX)
- ネットワーク1:NAT ケーブル接続
- ネットワーク2:ホストオンリーアダプタ ケーブル接続
- セキュリティソフト：McAfee Live save
  ファイアウォールは無効にして実施。

**お試し環境**

- Processor: Intel 第五世代Core i7(モバイル用途）
- メモリ： 8G
- 仮想化ソフト：Oracle VirtualBox 6.0
- 仮想化運用：Vagrant 2.2.2
- ホストOS: Windows 10 Home 20H2
- ゲストOS: CentOS 8 (Vagrantのcentos/8=公式BOX)
- ネットワーク1:NAT ケーブル接続
- ネットワーク2:ホストオンリーアダプタ ケーブル接続
- セキュリティソフト：McAfee Live save
  ファイアウォールは有効にして実施。また発生環境とは同一ネットワーク内。
  （同じルータにぶら下がっています。）

---

#### 追加試行

VirtualBoxを6.1から6.0に戻して実行したところ以下のメッセージを出力し、VM自体起動しませんでした。

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

できなくて困ることではないので、しばらくまって問題なければクローズしてしまいます。

Comment: VirtualBox の仮想ネットワークアダプタがどの設定を使用しているのか、ホストOS側のネットワークでプロキシやファイアーウォール等を使っているのか、辺りの情報も可能であれば追記してみてください。

Comment: 追記してみました。

Comment: 少しでもファイルのダウンロードが不完全ならチェックサムが変わるのは当たり前なので、毎回同じようなサイズで途切れてしまうのか、あとは別のダウンロード方法 (curl やブラウザ) を使っても問題が出るのか、辺りを試して問題点を切り分けていくしか無いかなと思います。

Comment: はい。質問にも書いたpip でもwgetの他 curlでもファイルのダウンロードの結果が変わります。ところがサイズは一定という。。。なんともな状態なのが。。。参考まで同一ホストのなかで動くWSLは必ず成功します。というかそもそもそこまで（毎回必ず発生する）ほど信頼性低いもんでもなかろうなので。。VagrantもしくはVirtualBoxの問題ではないかと思っている次第です。ただしVagrant関係なくVM起動させて実行しても結果は同じなので、VirtualBoxの方が怪しですね。AMD＋VirtualVMでなんかあるのではと勝手に思っているのですがそこから先が。。同様の問題を抱えている人が他所に１人だけいましたがそこにも解決情報はなく。

Comment: 例えばホスト経由でscpで該当のファイルを送って、チェックするとどうなりますか？

Comment: @あとわいと ファイルサイズは同一なのに、チェックサムだけ異なるということですか？ / 試しに `tar` で展開を試すとどうなるでしょうか？ (破損していた場合にはエラーになるはず)

Comment: @cubick さん。ファイルサイズは同一でチェックサムが異なるということです。伸長すると、ある場合は特定ファイルだけ展開され、その次はできなくなるなど様々です。

Comment: @keitaro_so さん。ありがとうございます。まだご指定のパターンは試していません（やろうとしていた段階で期待通り動作する環境があることに気づいたので。。）。試行したら結果を連携しますね。

Comment: @keitaro_so さん。本日試したところホスト⇒ゲストへのputでは問題ないことがわかりました。もしかしたら、HTTPだけなんですかね。curl ng/wget ng/pip ngです。

Comment: 関連情報 [Request https file download error from virtualbox 6.1.6 vm](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19532), [Corrupted downloads over network with hyperv backend](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19695) 最終的に(2020/10/20) "Fixed in 6.1.16" となっています。

Comment: @metropolis さん。ありがとうございます。やっぱりバグだったんですね。しかもバグパレードにあるとか。。。確かに6.1.14（最新）をDLしています。了解しました。6.1.16で問題ないことを確認できたら、その結果を共有して本件完了とします。ご意見いただいた皆さんありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメント欄での @metropolis さんのアドバイスに基づき、最新版の 6.1.18 を導入してみました。

導入後に状況は改善され、問題なく動作することを確認できました。
参考までに、Oracleのサイトではなく、VirtualBoxのサイトに最新版はあるようです。

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

**変更前:**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo pip3 install numpy
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/b2/6c7545bb7a38754d63048c7696804a0d947328125d81bf12beaa692c3ae3/numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    numpy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/b2/6c7545bb7a38754d63048c7696804a0d947328125d81bf12beaa692c3ae3/numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=8b5e972b43c8fc27d56550b4120fe6257fdc15f9301914380b27f74856299fea:
        Expected sha256 8b5e972b43c8fc27d56550b4120fe6257fdc15f9301914380b27f74856299fea
             Got        04a7353da49fb68cf6e47fd49f3c99112ec877887726c1656339bd275d6c3287
```

**変更後:**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo pip3 install numpy
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/b2/6c7545bb7a38754d63048c7696804a0d947328125d81bf12beaa692c3ae3/numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.4MB 100kB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy
```

なお、VirtualBoxのUpdate後は `Vagrant destroy⇒Vargrant up` して一度VMを消して再構築しないと状況は改善されませんでした。このことから、VMのイメージに問題を埋め込んでいるものと思われます。

みなさんの支援のおかげで本件解決に至りました。
ありがとうございます。